# SQL Make Table (from .mdb) to Point Shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, sql

For my school assignment, I must compose an SQL statement which retrieves data from a database in .mdb format.  I have no problem developing the SQL statement.  It is a requirement that we have an actual .sql file included in the submission of the assignment.  The thing that I am unsure about is how to go from this SQL file to a point shapefile.

I'll give a little bit of context that may help answering this question.  The point of the assignment is creating a web map in the end.  Because the performance of web mapping increases when there is less data, certain data (the data to be displayed online) must be extracted from the database.  So I get the whole web mapping concept, where before I can start, I need an actual map (.mxd) document.  In order to complete the map document, I need this point shapefile, which must be derived from an SQL statement. Going from SQL file to point shapefile is where I'm lost.

Comment: Clarification is needed. An .mdb file is a Microsoft Access database. As it happens, ArcGIS stores what it calls a Personal Geodatabase in this format. A shapefile is a specific file format (.shp plus other associated files) though the *term* is often applied to any geometry layer. Within a geodatabase the proper term is feature class. What exactly is in the database your SQL is querying? Does it *have* a point feature class or just a table with coordinates? Your assignment may be to create a query, save it as an sql file, and *export the results* to a new feature class or shapefile.

Comment: The database contains six tables, one of them has coordinates for 12 wineries.  The other tables contain sales data, product information etc. with hundreds of records.  A Make Table function must be used in SQL to create a single table with co-ordinates, aggregated sales data for each winery, etc.

Comment: If the winery table has only coordinates, and no field called 'shape' or 'geometry' or similar, then klewis's answer below mostly covers what you need beyond selecting an appropriate coordinate system for the coordinates you have. (If it *does* have a shape attribute you can skip the XY process because the data already has geometry.) You don't necessarily have to export a csv since ArcGIS can read an .mdb database - just add the SQL created table to an ArcGIS session (Add Data button) and use XY as described below, exporting a separate shapefile or featureclass in the .mdb of the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your SQL data to a .csv file. ArcGIS has a tool named "Make XY Event Layer" that maps X,Y columns from a csv or other table to an Layer. You can then Copy the Point Layer to a Shapefile. This tool works with any ArcGIS license level.

Comment: I don't recommend using csv files; you might get away with it for a small file but I have found unexpected issues with extended csv data (thousands to hundreds of thousands of rows). Seeing as the data is already in JET (Access) format I would consume it straight from there... I've not experienced problems in database x,y to shape.